How do you remove an application handler for an application you have uninstalled?
I installed 'MS-Teams for home and school', then uninstalled it.
Unfortunately the .pkg installer configured a msteams: handler that would launch the application, so every time I click the link I get an error "There us no application set to open the URL..."
How do I remove it?
(A side effect of this question is I hope to learn how app handlers work on macOS!)


@Stephen How did you get this error dialog? By clicking on an "msteams://" URL? Or a microsoft shortlink that redirects you to this URL? Or a button in an app/website? I suspect it is microsoft related bug, who insists you still have msteams installed, so it tries to open the local app.

@nohillside it is a url scheme registered in LaunchServices (see command lsregister) used to directly pull up the msteams app and enter the meeting. safari will not be able to fulfill that request.

@hym3242 ah, right. Wonder (as you do) what the OP clicked on initially. Just sent myself a Teams invite, all links there are https links.

Looks like your browser is set to automatically open Teams via the msteams: link provided by the Teams website. Disabling this depends on the browser used, which one do you use?

@nohillside Google Chrome. Just checked safari and it doesn't trigger the error.

I assume you configured Chrome to always open msteams links in Teams. Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a way to undo this within Chrome itself.
I'm aware of two ways to remove them, both require you to quit Chrome first.

If you feel comfortable with editing JSON files, you can open ~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Profile 1/Preferences, search for the msteams entry and delete it.

Otherwise, the only way seems to be to remove the whole file (and loose all your preferences).

